# Finite extension fields of odd degree over $F_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I'm actually getting stuck on an earlier part of this problem, but once I have it I think the rest is clear. First (part (a)), it's obvious that for positive, odd $k, 2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/k \mathbb{Z}$. Now I'm trying to prove part (b), that there exists a positive integer $\ell$ such that $2^{\ell} = \overline{1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/k \mathbb{Z}$. This is obvious with small examples, but I'm missing how to show it in general. Please, just a hint to start with, and I'll add a comment if I'm giving up.

Building on this question, I need to show (part (c)) that there exists a finite extension field $F$ of the field $\mathbb{F}_{2} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ such that all $k$'th roots of unity exist in $F$. Unless I'm mistaken, this should be $\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]/(x^{k} - 1)$. And for a particular $k$ (part (d)), the smallest such extension should be $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{k})$.

Comment: The same $k$ for the exponent and the modulus?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same $k$. BTW, just edited the post to add that I just need a hint for now, because this looks like it should be a fairly simple problem, so hopefully I can wrap it up with a limited prompt.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{2^n} = \mathbb{F}_{2}(\zeta_{2^n-1}) = \mathbb{F}_{2}(\zeta_{m})$ for any $m$ such that $n = \text{order}(2 \bmod m )$. In that case the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_m$ is $\prod_{k=1}^n (x-\zeta_m^{2^k})$ (of degree $m$)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, though at the moment I'm just proving 2 has finite order.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at the wrong exponent to answer your question. The order of $2$ needn't be $k$. (Edited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result holds in an abstract setting. Namely every element of a finite group has finite order. Hint:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $x \in G$ then the powers $x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, \dots$ cannot all be distinct.

What is the relevant group that we can use to show that $2^k = 1$ in $\mathbf{Z}/k\mathbf{Z}$? Answer:

> The group of units: $\{a \in \mathbf{Z}/k\mathbf{Z} : \gcd(a,k) = 1\}$ with multiplication as the group operation.

Comment: In the hint, I assume the sequence terminates with $x^{n}$ where $n$ is the order of the group. That makes sense.

In fact, come to think of it, shouldn't $\ell|\phi(k)$, since the order of the cyclic group generated by $2$ has to divide the order of $G$ by Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: @BMac Yes Lagrange's theorem is applicable here. For the hint though, you can't assume the sequence goes like $1, x^1, x^2, \dots, x^n = 1$. For instance, what if $x \ne 1$ and $x^1 = x^2 = x^3 = \cdots$? You can show that this cannot happen in a group. but simply "not being distinct" isn't enough to conclude this.

Comment: I was just concluding that if you had $n + 1$ distinct powers of $x$, this would result in too many elements for a group of order $n$.

Comment: @BMac Right, but what it gives you isn't $x^n = 1$ it's $x^n = x^m$ where $n \ne m$.